# What is the operator norm of the symmetric difference operator on a finite periodic lattice?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let \begin{equation}
\Lambda_n:=\{ -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^n}, \cdots, 0 ,\cdots ,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^n} , \frac{1}{2} \}
\end{equation}
be a finite lattice and think of the vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ defined as
\begin{equation}
V_n:=\{ \text{all }f: \Lambda_n \to \mathbb{C} \mid f\text{ is periodic } \}
\end{equation}

Then, since $\Lambda_n$ is a finite set, $V_n$ is clearly a finite dimensional vector space. We can give the inner product on $V_n$ in an obvious way as well.

However, I am quite confused about the following linear operator:
\begin{equation}
D : V_n \to V_n 
\end{equation}
defined as \begin{equation}
(Df)(x):=2^{n+1}[f(x+\frac{1}{2^n})-f(x-\frac{1}{2^n})]
\end{equation}

This is clearly a well-defined linear operator on $V_n$ and thus must have a matrix representation. I can see that it has no diagonal components so that its trace is always zero, regardless of $n$.

However, what about its operator norm? I am stuck at calculating it. Does the norm depend on $n$? Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Well, a shoddy numerical experiment on Octave leads me to conjecture that the answer is $\|D\|_2\approx 2^{(n+2)}$. The pairs of $(n, \|D\|_2)$ were (1,  6.93), (2, 15.22), (3, 31.51),
(4, 63.73),
(5, 127.86),
(6,  255.93),
(7,  511.96),
(8,  1023.98)
(9,   2047.99)
(10, 4096.00)

Comment: And just some interpretation here -- this would be consistent with what I know about symmetric difference operators on other domains as well. Usually, the more you refine, the more poorly-conditioned the operator becomes. In finite-dimensional spaces we're fine, but on an infinite-dimensional space, differentiation is an unbounded linear operator. So it kinda makes sense :-)

Comment: Do you know Fourier Analysis, or just the discrete Fourier transform?

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes I know those topics.